# joining two databases together

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have two databases

**Database 1:** (Allows users to add posts similar to a blog):

posts table

Users Table

Categories Table

**Database 2:**

Users table

few other tables irrelevant for this question

---

What I am after is letting users from Database 2 add posts to database 1 using database 1 categories, but I am unsure how to control this as both databases have users table and the uids are used in many other tables in each database + maintaining 2 mysql links in php is not very easy if the connection identifier was not used in queries when building the scripts especially because both scripts were written like 6 years ago so no fancy stuffs just simple functional scripts.

What's the easiest way to get around this problem ?

Comment: I haven't noticed the check "Acceptance check" until now :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this, as [discussed in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094168/881224), but I've highlighted the answer that, I feel, is the best solution for the long term.

Yes, this will require you to tear down a lot of your key constraints and other table-based relationships, but you can repeat this process indefinitely and suffer no consequence (outside of a little headache).

p.s. [the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1094213/881224) for that same post is a common workaround for generating new unique ids, but you'll have to lift any columns that have a AUTO_INCREMENT property for it to work.

Comment: Thanks, I will choose one of the ways described there, after carefully evaluating both scripts to decide the easiest & less errors prone way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you really want to be sure that the data is gotten from the correct databases, you HAVE to edit your queries and add the database name.

There would just be another way: If you know before the action how to limit the data properly (you already know some where's), you can read them once per database and store them in PHP. But remember: This is a very laggy and imperformant way, so just use this if you are really sure to not handle too much data.

Comment: The problem is each database has to access data from the other, so I'll have to edit both scripts for the change which will take too much time as these are relatively old scripts and not written in MVC so I'll have to lookup queries here & there to get this resolved.

Comment: And the uid might exists in both sides, so I'll have to add another column for the second db in the posts table.
That's the only way I'm thinking of right now, I was hoping there's a simpler way that won't take up too much time.